# how to seperate compadd values with line break (zsh)

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a `compadd` function that is meant to list AWS instances tags and return that list as completion options.

```
_aws_instance_by_name() {
# TODO: Figure out partial completion
local instances=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value}" --output text)
  [[ ${DEBUG} ]] && echo -e "\033[34;1m[DEBUG]\033[0m ${instances}"
  compadd ${instances}
}
compdef _aws_instance_by_name aws_instance_id_by_name
```

But when I hit tab I get all options in option delimited by `\n`

`foo\nbar\nSuper fancy`

How do I *split* each value into the returned suggestions?

Comment: Try using an array for the instances variable: `local instrances=( $(aws...) )`
Then use `compadd -a instances`
I'm unsure of the exact output of the aws command so if that doesn't work, it may need splitting. For debug, use the `_complete_debug` widget (Ctrl-X,? by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
#compdef aws_instance_id_by_name

# Wrap output in double quotes to 
# preserve all whitespace.
local output="$( <command> )"

# Split on line breaks.
local -a instances=( "${(f)output}" )

# Use convenience function to get 
# fancy completion features for 
# free. No need to figure out 
# partial completion yourself.
_wanted aws-instances 'AWS instance' \
    compadd -a instances
```

If you paste the above into a text file whose name starts with `_` and save it into a dir that’s in your `$fpath`, it will get picked up automatically when you run `compinit`. No need to call `compdef`.

Documentation:

- [Command substitution](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Command-Substitution)
- [Parameter expansion flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)
- Completion system:

  - [Utility functions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-Functions)
  - [Autoloaded files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files)